# How to execute two AsyncTask in one class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to execute two AsyncTask in one class one by one.

I have try like this

```
class LoginProcess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_Activity.this);          
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            //Request Making        
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            try {
            if(login){
                                                                 //Call another AsyncTask
                    new GetFav().execute();
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    class GetFav extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_Activity.this);          
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                                                                             //Request Making
                //Getting the results from response

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();          
            }
        }
    }
```

First task is login activity. The second task is get the favDetails. 
It is working fine in emulator. But when i try to execute in mobile i am getting error. The page is navigate after login success. But favDetails is empty. After navigation only the favDetail task is executing in device. Please let me know how to use two async task in one class one by one.

My Error is:-

```
    12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): Process: info.androidhive.googlemapsv2, PID: 31294
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.ExpandableDrawerAdapter.getChildrenCount(ExpandableDrawerAdapter.java:61)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.refreshExpGroupMetadataList(ExpandableListConnector.java:567)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.expandGroup(ExpandableListConnector.java:698)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:698)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:651)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3467)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4830)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
12-12 06:34:47.641: E/AndroidRuntime(31294): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am getting this error when i click the slide menu. I load the slide menu item in runtime. Now the items are empty. That's why i am getting error.

My first page is login page. Second page is welcome page. In that page i have slide menu with dynamic items. All the items will get on login screen. If login is success i will get the items from server and load the items to slide menu. But the second asyncTask is not working. That's why i am getting this error.

Now please let me any idea to execute the AsyncTask one by one.

Sorry for poor english..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you can call the other on the postExecute() of first one and Alternatively you can use : SERIAL_EXECUTOR .

Comment: @Kanchan, no he cannot use SERIAL_EXECUTOR w/o some hand-work, as the 2nd task is to be executed conditionally

Comment: I would like to know, why you cannot put all your code in ONE AsyncTask instead of using two?

Comment: @Christopher.. If login success, then only another task should run. Otherwise it should not run..

Comment: @NewDeveloper After login task you navigate to welcome page as well as start GetFav task?

Comment: @vipul mittal.. Yes..

Comment: @NewDeveloper what do you do with the results? Do you set them to some global variable and use in welcome page or Do you call a function on welcome page to pass the results?

Comment: @vipul mittal.. I am using as a global variable..

Comment: @NewDeveloper if the global variable is null give it some initial value maybe empty list or something. I think the problem is that on device the you go to next page and try to see this global variable before task is able to fetch it.

Comment: @vipulmittal.. Now i realize the problem. Thanks for your question. In the second AsyncTask only i am fetching the values. I navigate the page befor fetching the values. That's why only I am getting this error. Now I navigate the page after second asyncTask. Now it is working good.. :-)

Comment: @NewDeveloper But why can't you place the code for your 2nd asynctask inside doInBackground() of 1st AsyncTask. I do not understand, why you have start the 2nd AsyncTask inside onPostExecute of the 1st one.

Comment: I don't know how to start the second AsyncTask after the first AsyncTask. My first AsyncTask is Login Process. If login success, Then only the second AsyncTask should start. If login failed second task should not perform. That's why only i give like this. I don't know this is correct way/ effective way to do this process. I post this question for the effective solution.

Answer (score -1):

You should set a Handler in your activity to execute the second AsyncTask and then call that Handler from `onPostExecute` method of the first AsyncTask.

Comment: AsyncTask have in-build handler know?? If i use another handler there may any error occur??? If not can you post a sample code please??